# DB2 System Tables Logs?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'm using DB2 LUW. I'm working on looking at how often data is being changed or added into our database, and I was curious if there was a system table that I might be able to find this information?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what you mean. You will for example find the #commit and #rollback in sysibmadm.snapdb, #rows_written per table can be found in sysibmadm.snaptab. If you take snapshots from those on a regular basis you get an idea on how often data is updated. Was that what you had in mind, or is it something else you are looking for?